# Game In Java Not Adding JLabel With Icon

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a basic game in Java that is going to be similar to 2d games where you dodge asteroids in a space ship.

My issue is that for some reason some of my asteroids are not correctly being added to my JFrame.

Here is how I add my JLabel's (asteroids):

**NOTE: SpriteSheet.java is a valid and functioning class that does successfully return the image.**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Entity extends JLabel {

    private int asteroidSizeW = 72;
    private int asteroidSizeH = 72;
    private int entities = 5;

    public Entity() {
        List<Integer> asteroidLocations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random ran = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < entities; i++) {
            if (asteroidLocations.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < asteroidLocations.size(); j++) {
                    int chosenSpawn = ran.nextInt(Frame.WIDTH - 72);
                    if (chosenSpawn > (asteroidLocations.get(j) + 72) || chosenSpawn < (asteroidLocations.get(j) - 72)) {
                        System.out.println("Made it!");
                        System.out.println(asteroidLocations);
                        asteroidLocations.add(chosenSpawn);
                        setIcon(new SpriteSheet().load("asteroids.png", 0, 0, asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH));
                        setLocation(chosenSpawn, 0);
                        setSize(asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                int x = ran.nextInt(Frame.WIDTH - 72);
                asteroidLocations.add(x);

                setIcon(new SpriteSheet().load("asteroids.png", 0, 0, asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH));
                setLocation(x, 0);
                setSize(asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After testing I have found out that the first JLabel is being added (the else in):

```
if (asteroidLocations.size() > 0) {
} else {
// this is being executed once (like it should)
}
```

**In other words, the first image (JLabel) does display in the game.**

Everything else does work as intended as seen here by the output:

```
Made it!
[181]
Made it!
[181, 273]
Made it!
[181, 273, 452]
Made it!
[181, 273, 452, 627]
```

It seems like it has an issue returning the JLabel inside the nested loop.

Could anybody please help me out? Thanks.

**FULL CLASS:**

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Frame extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
    private String TITLE = "Asteroid Killer";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.createFrame();
        f.showFrame();
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        setTitle(TITLE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        add(new MainPanel());
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    private void showFrame() {
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel() {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        //add(new Minimap());
        add(new Entity());
    }
}

/*@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Minimap extends JPanel {
    public Minimap() {
        setBounds(284, 0, 100, 100); // x,y,width,height
        setBackground(Color.RED); 
    }
}*/

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Entity extends JLabel {

    private int asteroidSizeW = 72;
    private int asteroidSizeH = 72;
    private int entities = 5;

    public Entity() {
        List<Integer> asteroidLocations = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random ran = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < entities; i++) {
            if (asteroidLocations.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < asteroidLocations.size(); j++) {
                    int chosenSpawn = ran.nextInt(Frame.WIDTH - 72);
                    if (chosenSpawn > (asteroidLocations.get(j) + 72) || chosenSpawn < (asteroidLocations.get(j) - 72)) {
                        System.out.println("Made it!");
                        System.out.println(asteroidLocations);
                        asteroidLocations.add(chosenSpawn);
                        setIcon(new SpriteSheet().load("asteroids.png", 0, 0, asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH));
                        setLocation(chosenSpawn, 0);
                        setSize(asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                int x = ran.nextInt(Frame.WIDTH - 72);
                asteroidLocations.add(x);

                setIcon(new SpriteSheet().load("asteroids.png", 0, 0, asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH));
                setLocation(x, 0);
                setSize(asteroidSizeW, asteroidSizeH);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could rattle a few dozen, thousand reasons why this might not work, or you could consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. Before you tell us it's to large, the purpose of a runnable example is to be a cut down version which demonstrates the issue you are facing...

Comment: I have posted the full class at the end of the post, not including the spritesheet class.

Answer (score 0):

You logic is around backwards.  You are only ever adding a single `JLabel` to your container...

```
add(new Entity());
```

You actually `Entity` class has no means to put anything onto the screen other than a single representation of itself...which is typically the last thing it created within it's for loop...

Instead of trying to create multiple entities within your `Entity` class (I know, you're only setting the properties, but the intention is the same), move the creation process out to the the `MainPanel` and physically create a new `Entity` on each loop

Now, having said that, screwing with components in this manner is probably not the best solution.  You should consider using a custom painting approach, you will find it easier to manage all the entities and will probably also consume less overhead...

Consider having a look at

- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

for more details

Comment: This means that I can not define my `asteroidLocations` list where it is or else it will be reset every time the loop is run. How can I dodge that? I don't want to define it in any other class.

Comment: There are a number of ways you might approach the problem, assuming you want to continue using component based entities.  You could define a single entity manager, that is responsible for managing ALL the entities in the system, including creating, updating and destorying them.  Equally, you could create a `LayoutManager` which allows you to define the properties of individual entities and allows you to work within the confines of the existing component based API. Or you could simply run through all the components contained within the current container and mangle them manually.